# dnsmasq captive portal with ipset/nft "allowed list"

Tags: linux, nginx, dnsmasq

I'm playing with dnsmasq to create some kind of captive portal.

Idea is:
`dnsmasq` by default rewrite all DNS requests to local ip (`address=/#/123.123.123.123`), and `nginx` is already setup here to display "access restricted page".

But i want to add some kind of excluding list:

```
ipset create captive-allowed hash:ip
ipset add captive-allowed 222.222.222.222
```

That will contains IP address of clients, that shouldn't be rewritten by `/#/` and will use dnsmasq as proxy to `1.1.1.1/1.0.0.1` to pass real ips.

As i understood, `dnsmasq`'s ipset setting, only work for each domain. So i have to do:

```
ipset=/google.com/captive-allowed/go.ogle.real.ip
ipset=/amazon.com/captive-allowed/ama.zon.real.ip
... billion records more ...
```

Is my assumption right? Or maybe i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do that through dnsmasq at all – getting DNS involved only adds unneeded complexity (caching, DNSSEC failures, easy to bypass even by accident, etc). Instead, use only iptables/nft to redirect all HTTP packets at IP level (using DNAT via `-j DNAT` or `-j REDIRECT`). For example:

```
-A FORWARD_CAPTIVE -m set --match-set AllowedClientsMAC src -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD_CAPTIVE -j REJECT
<...>
-A PREROUTING_CAPTIVE -m set --match-set AllowedClientsMAC src -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING_CAPTIVE -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.53
-A PREROUTING_CAPTIVE -p tcp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.53
-A PREROUTING_CAPTIVE -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT
-A PREROUTING_CAPTIVE -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT
```

Comment: The problem is in... this is remote devices, and I can't do normal forwarding... or...
Hm.... you gave me a good idea to redirect allowed clients to external dnses... using iptables! tyvm!